# Rewriting Oracle query/update without IN condition for comparison's sake

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

Oracle here. I have the following tables:

```
[orders]
===
order_id : integer constraint pk_orders primary key using index
order_name : varchar2(40 char)
order_ordered_by : integer constraint fk_shoppers references accounts
order_total : number(10,2) not null
order_status : char not null

[line_items]
===
line_item_id : integer constraint pk_line_items primary key using index
order_id : integer not null constraint fk_line_items_orders references orders on delete cascade
product_id : integer not null constraint fk_line_items_products references products
line_item_quantity : integer not null

[products]
===
product_id : integer constraint pk_products primary key using index
product_name : varchar2(40 char)
product_category : varchar2(10 char)
product_available_on : date
```

I am trying to write a query that updates orders and sets their statuses to "ORDERED" where:

- the `orders.order_status` is currently "PENDING"; and
- the `products.product_category` is currently "COFFEE"; and
- the `products.product_available_on` is currently less than or equal to the present time (now)

My best attempt thus far *does* work and get the job done:

```
UPDATE orders
SET status = 'ORDERED'
WHERE order_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT orders.order_id
    FROM orders
    INNER JOIN line_items ON line_items.orderId = orders.order_id
    INNER JOIN products ON line_items.product_id = products.product_id
    WHERE
        orders.status = 'PENDING' AND
        products.product_category = 'COFFEE' AND
        products.product_available_on <= CURRENT_DATE
);
```

Again, this *does* work, however its pretty slow so I'm trying to see if there is a way I can rewrite this to be more efficient where I'm not using the `IN` condition (I've read in several places that `IN` can cause performance issues in Oracle). Is there any way to accomplish rewriting this query without the `IN` so I can compare performance?

**Please note:** changing the tables (tweaking their fields, adding constraints/indexes/anything) is out of the realm of possibility in my particular use case!

Comment: Be wary of sources that tell you to avoid fundamental elements of the SQL language, such as the `IN` operator.  They are at best over-generalizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would *start* with this:

```
UPDATE orders o
SET    o.status = 'ORDERED'
WHERE  o.status = 'PENDING'
AND    EXISTS ( SELECT 'line for available coffee'
                FROM   line_items li
                INNER JOIN products p ON p.product_id = li.product_id
                WHERE  li.order_id = o.order_id
                AND    p.product_category = 'COFFEE'
                AND    p.product_available_on <= SYSDATE );
```

This is better than your posted query for a few reasons.

1. It only looks at the `ORDERS` table once.
2. The `EXISTS` allows
   Oracle to stop looking for rows in the correlated subquery one it
   finds one.
3. It moves the `order_status = 'PENDING'` condition to
   the main `UPDATE`, making it easier for the optimizer to realize
   that it can use an index on `order_status`.

If you don't have an index on order status, consider one.  Make sure you gather stats with histograms (that'll mostly happen automatically nowadays, depending on what version of Oracle you have).

Why are histograms important?  Because your `order_status` values are very likely to be skewed (i.e., not evenly distributed).  That is, one would expect many, many orders with a status of "CLOSED" or maybe "ORDERED" or "ON HOLD" (making these up...), so that a relatively small percentage of them have status "PENDING".  Without a histogram, all Oracle will see is a index with 1,000,000 values and 4 distinct values -- and Oracle is unlikely to use such an index.  The histograms give it the extra information to know that, if you want "CLOSED" orders, it *is* a bad index; but if you want "PENDING" orders, it's a good one.